# Find minimum weight vertex subset whose removal yields a fully disconnected subgraph

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I have an undirected graph $G$ with weighted vertices, $V$, and seek to find a minimally weighted subset of vertices, $k \in V$, whose removal would yield a full disconnected subgraph $S=G[V$ \ $k]$.

Example:
G = V, E where

V (vertex index:weight)=
{(0: 1),(1: 2),(2: 2),(3: 1)}

E= {(0,1),(1,2),(2,3),(3,0)}

then, k={0,3} with total weight of 2
and S is vertices 1 and 2 (no edges)

This seems like something a max-flow approach would work for, but I am looking to remove vertices rather than edges here so a direct application does not seem obvious.

Incidentally, this can easily be phrased as a matrix problem by taking the adjacency matrix of G and adding to it a diagonal matrix whose entries are the weights of V. We would then seek to remove (or zero out) same-index row-column pairs to yield a diagonal matrix with maximized trace

Matrix version of example above:

original matrix [ [1, 1, 0, 1], [1, 2, 1, 0], [0, 1, 2, 1], [1, 0, 1, 1] ]

solution: zero out row 0 and column 0, zero out row 3 and column 3

yields diagonal matrix: [ [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0], [0, 0, 2, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0] ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a a fully-disconnected graph, we need to delete all the edges, so the selected vertices must form a vertex cover.   The special case where all weights are $1$ is the [minimum vertex cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover) problem, which is known to be NP-hard.

If you Google "minimum weight vertex cover", which is the problem you describe, you'll get a number of hits, but I haven't looked into any of them.  https://zenodo.org/record/1076814/files/11182.pdf
is described as "An Effective Algorithm for Minimum Weighted Vertex Cover," but I don't see how this can be, unless it's an approximation algorithm, or "effective" just means that it's correct, not necessarily practicable.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I thought this problem seemed familiar. I will have a look at the paper. For my particular purpose I do not need the exact optimum, though it would be nice, but I have some rather large graphs (200k+ vertices) and a good approximation will suffice. This definitely helps and beats my last idea of just throwing it into simulated annealing.